# Linux folder has realm name appended

Tags: linux, sssd

I'm using RedHat with SSSD authentication against active directory.

There are 3 domains specified in the *sssd.conf* file with the default suffix specified for the domain where users reside.

When a new file is created using a domain account it is including the REALM (see below)

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 adm-rumno0-xeu@MY.DOMAIN domain users@MY.DOMAIN 6 Jun 12 15:32 test
drwxr-xr-x. 2 adm-rumno0-xeu@MY.DOMAIN domain users@MY.DOMAIN 6 Jun 12 15:36 test2
```

Because of the way yarn log aggregation is working, there is a mismatch between the user account its using (*adm-rumno0-xeu*) and the owner of the folder its trying to access (*adm-rumno0-xeu@MY.DOMAIN*)

What I need is

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 adm-rumno0-xeu domain users 6 Jun 12 15:32 test
drwxr-xr-x. 2 adm-rumno0-xeu domain users 6 Jun 12 15:36 test2
```

I have tried setting *use_fully_qualified_names* to *False* but that prevents login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by removing the `default_domain_suffix` from the `[sssd]` section and adding `use_fully_qualified_names = False` in the correct `[domain]` section.

so;

```
[sssd]
default_domain_suffix = 

[our_domain]
use_fully_qualified_names = False
```